# Blender Crashes when i use Python Script

Tags: python, blender

I have a python script which works fine but it is not working Blender freezes as install the addon and Execute it as I have mentioned the code itself works fine.
Here Is the Final code:

```
def main(context):
     # You should change this varibale in "here" to match your own directory path
     # use '/' or '\\' for hirecacy
    target_dir = "C:/Users/Arpit/Desktop/UV/" 
    selObj = []

    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        selObj.append(obj.name)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

    # --- while-loop ---
    
    i = 0

    while i < len(selObj):
        obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        full_file_name = target_dir + bpy.data.objects[selObj[i]].name
        dirname = os.path.dirname(full_file_name)

        # inside `while`-loop
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)

        bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath=full_file_name, mode='PNG', size=(4096, 4096), opacity=0.6)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

        i += 1
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Or you could also use module `logging` to save these information in file and later check this file. maybe this way you will see in which place is problem. You could also use `try/except` to catch errors and write in `logging`

Comment: maybe you have wrong indentations - you check `while i < ...` but you set `i = i + 1` outside this `while` so it never stops it. Maybe `if not os.path.exists(dirname):        os.makedirs(dirname)` should have different indentation. OR you can use  `os.makedirs(dirname, exist_ok=True)` without `if`. OR maybe you should use `for item in selObj:` and instead of `i = 0`, `while` and `i += 1`. And later you should use `item` instead of `selObj[i]`

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it but I see some mistakes with indentations - and this can make problem and code may run in endless loop and freeze program.

You put `if` in the same column as `while` so it finishs `while-loop` and rest is executed after exiting this loop. But this loop check `i` to exit and now you have `i += 1` outside this loop so it never change this `i`.

If you change indentations then `if` will be inside loop and `i += 1` will be also inside loop and this should resolve problem with freezing.

```
def main(context):

    target_dir = "C:/Users/Arpit/Desktop/UV/" 
    selObj = []

    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        selObj.append(obj.name)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

    # --- while-loop ---
    
    i = 0

    while i < len(selObj):
        obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        full_file_name = target_dir + bpy.data.objects[selObj[i]].name
        dirname = os.path.dirname(full_file_name)

        # inside `while`-loop
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)

        bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath=full_file_name, mode='PNG', size=(4096, 4096), opacity=0.6)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

        i += 1
```

But frankly I would do it with `for`-loop and it wouldn't need `i = 0`, `i += 1` and `selObj[i]` but only `item`

```
    # --- for-loop ---

    # without `i = 0`

    for item in selObj:

        obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

        # `item` instead of `selObj[i]`
        full_file_name = target_dir + bpy.data.objects[ item ].name
        dirname = os.path.dirname(full_file_name)

        # inside `while`-loop
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)

        bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath=full_file_name, mode='PNG', size=(4096, 4096), opacity=0.6)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

        # without `i += 1`
```

Comment: Thank you Code started working now but the object it is selecting in not correct. Lets say i have four object so it is selecting like "First Object" then "It is combining all the 4 object" then again "first object" then "It is combining all the 4 objec"

Comment: I have no idea how works Blender and I have no idea what you want to select. I resolved main problem - with freezing - so now you should create new question on new page with new problem. And you should better describe problem because we can't read in your mind. At start I suggest to use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: Actually i found the error you forgot to add item in the above line that is why it was not working properly
    for item in selObj:
# Here obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0] it should be like this
            obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[item]